# How to fix an error with libsn0wcore "Failed to link opensn0w_cli!"?

Tags: ubuntu, github, libusb, pastebin

I'm Brunodm.
I keep getting this error (http://pastebin.com/NAApFYju)
when I try to compile opensn0w (https://github.com/winocm/opensn0w) by @winocm in Ubuntu, that I've just reinstalled.
I think I need some libraries to make it works, but I don't know which. Could anyone help me to fix this error?
Thanks in advance,
Brunodm.

Comment: I've installed libusb-dev. I did apt-get update; apt-get upgrade... but nothing, still get this error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch the opensn0w source code. Go to the root of the source, and download this: http://devbug.me/attachment/4174303333.zip and unzip it. Then run:

patch -p1 < opensn0w3.diff